# Navigation menu is wacky on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to simplify the code behind my client's website, as there was some extraneous code. While doing this, the navigation menu (bootstrap) no longer works? It seems to be off screen and I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

```
<div id="container-para" class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse bg-inverse justify-content-around fixed-top" >
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">    
        <img src="/inc/img/IMG_1877.jpg" alt="Cheapest Used Tires" style="padding-right:1px;border-radius: 6%;"><span>Cheapest Used Tires</span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <img class="logo3" src="/inc/img/3logo.jpg">
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-justify text-center">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dealersDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img class="logo3" src="/inc/img/3logo.jpg">
Tire Dealers</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dealersDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/tire-dealers.php">Tire Dealers</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/construction.php">Tire Services</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/construction.php">All Auto Services</a>
            </div>  
        </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/construction.php">Why Used?</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/construction.php">Tire Science</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/construction.php">Tire Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/NewPages/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form method="post" action="/auth/user/users.php">
            <button class="nav-item nav-link buttons">Login or Join</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3rfkrgc/2/

Comment: You didn't include Bootstrap 4 in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that Bootstrap 3 code doesn't work with Bootstrap 4 css. Bootstrap 4 is almost a complete rewrite of Bootstrap 3. So, **almost everything has changed**.

Here's what a working Bootstrap 4 navbar looks like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Notice: There are no `navbar-default` and no `navbar-toggleable-*` classes to start with. Also, it's a good idea to keep your HTML valid. (some of yours is not)

Bootstrap 4 navbar reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/